# Jquery closures in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to create a plugin where I pass on handler functions for specific events.  In the simple example below, I have two buttons.  When I press button 1, its label should change to 'Button A', and when I press button 2, its label should change to 'Button B'.

However, what is happening is when I press button 1, the label changes to 'Button B'.  I know this has something to do with the handler function closure in the loop, but I just can't figure out how to fix it.

```
<body>
    <button class="btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn2">Button 2</button>
</body>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
$(function() {

    $("body").myplugin( {
        helperFunctions : {
            funcA : function( obj ) {
                $(obj).text( "Button A" );
            },

            funcB : function( obj ) {
                $(obj).text( "Button B" );
            }
        },

        handlers : [
            {   
             on : "click",
             selector : ".btn1",
             handlerFunc : function( funcs, obj ){
                               funcs.funcA( obj );
                           }

            },

            {   
             on : "click",
             selector : ".btn2",
             handlerFunc : function( funcs, obj ){
                               funcs.funcB( obj );
                           }

            }
        ]
    });

});


(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        myplugin: function ( settings ) {
            var $this = $(this);

            function createHandlerFunction( func, obj ){
                return func( settings.helperFunctions, obj ) ;
            }

            for( var handlerIdx in settings.handlers ){
                var handler = settings.handlers[ handlerIdx ];
                $this.on(  
                     handler.on, 
                     handler.selector, 
                     function() { 
                         return createHandlerFunction( handler.handlerFunc, this ) } );
                     }
            }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Sorry if the example is a bit long.  Here's http://jsfiddle.net/30nL07db/

Comment: Put your function expression inside the `createHandlerFunction` (so that it is returned), not around the call, and it will work.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: you shouldn't be using `for..in` to iterate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/30nL07db/42/

```
for( var handlerIdx in settings.handlers ){
    var handler = settings.handlers[ handlerIdx ];
    $this.on(handler.on, handler.selector, handler, function(event) {
        return createHandlerFunction( event.data.handlerFunc, this );
    });
}
```

Simply pass the handler as data parameter to the event registration Or the variable handler will point to its last assigned value(i.e, the last value of loop);

Answer (score 2):

So the problem in your code is with this :

```
for( var handlerIdx in settings.handlers ){
    var handler = settings.handlers[ handlerIdx ];
...
```

Your are using in event delegation the `handler` variable, which is bound to the outer variable `handlerIdx`, and becouse of that when exiting the for loops, handlerIdx will be the last id...

Here is an contra-example with 3 id's : [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30nL07db/47/)

Look at other question about closures : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Tutorial about closures : [here](http://conceptf1.blogspot.ro/2013/11/javascript-closures.html)

So let's make a function which creates the event delegation, outside the loop, and inside just pass that function , like this :

```
function createEvent(id) {
    $this.on(
      settings.handlers[id].on,
      settings.handlers[id].selector,
      function() {
         settings.handlers[id].handlerFunc( settings.helperFunctions, this)
      }
    );
}

 for( var handlerIdx in settings.handlers ){
     var handler = settings.handlers[ handlerIdx ];
     var s = handler.selector;
     createEvent(handlerIdx);
 }
```

[See fiddle with this answer, working as you expect](http://jsfiddle.net/30nL07db/48/)